# A word for "a chance to makeup for past mistakes"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to use a single word that means "a chance to makeup for past mistakes." It would likely be a synonym of any of the words/phrases in the following list:

second chance

another opportunity

do-over

retry

makeup

retake

repeat

rerun

fresh start

I recognize that this is a long list, but none of the single words here work for me - they're all a little too on the nose. I'm inspired by the Biblical concept of the Jubilee year, a year in which all debts were forgiven. For further context, the word should be applicable in reference to technical mistakes (not necessarily moral mistakes) as demonstrated by the sentence below.

A sample use:

"Due to her poor job performance, her first annual evaluation at her new post was very negative. This made her eager for something of a(n) __________ so she could demonstrate her competence to her supervisor."

Comment: What was she going to repeat? Taking an exam? Or is this some major spiritual re-awakening or even reincarnation of her old soul in a new body? I think the context is important. Could you rewrite your sentence to make it less generic. Thanks

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the vague sample use. I've amended the question based on your suggestion.

Comment: Your makeup is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word that should go into the blank (your sample sentence) could well be **any coming opportunities**.

As far as the actual question is concerned, words such as *amends*, *reparations*, and @Anton's suggestion *atonement*, among many others work well.

**EDIT**— Since the OP has edited the question and provided an edited version of the sample sentence, I suggest that he go with **rectification**/**betterment** which seems to fit the bill quite nicely.

AHD defines the verb (*rectify*) as— **To set right; Correct**

Similarly, the same dictionary defines *betterment* as— **An improvement over what has been the case.**

Thus,

> Due to her poor job performance, her first annual evaluation at her new post was very negative. This made her eager for something of a **rectification**/ **betterment** so she could demonstrate her competence to her supervisor."

Comment: Thanks for this response, but I've realized my question was ill-posed. I've amended the question to clarify a bit more what I'm looking for. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Jared— I have edited my answer. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, these options certainly fit my sample sentence, but they are still not quite what I'm looking for. This may mean I'm having trouble communicating the concept I have in mind, or I'm looking for a word that doesn't exist. I'm quite picky here because I'll be using this word in a branding situation (as opposed to an expository one), so besides having the right meaning, it also needs to sound/feel a certain way. I'll leave the question open a little while longer, but if nothing else comes up I'll accept this answer in case it is helpful to future users.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a chance for *atonement*

> = something that you do to show that you are sorry for something bad that you did:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/atonement)

Seeking a parallel, I considered *Purgatory* as a place that offers opportunity to atone. But it is too strong and too religious a concept for you us. *confessional* offers the opportunity to admit to mistakes but is also religious and a bit weak on doing much about the errors. That only leaves me with *expiation*.

> Definition of expiate
>
> transitive verb:
> to make amends for
>
> “permission to expiate their offences by their assiduous labours”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expiate)

Comment: Yes, this is along the lines of what I'm looking for, except I want one word that means a "chance for atonement." Atonement is the act of making up for past mistakes, but what word describes the chance for atonement (as opposed to the act of atonement).

Comment: Thanks. I slept on it and have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From the sporting and entertainment worlds - **comeback**

> comeback  (kŭm′băk′) n.
>
> 1. a. A return to formerly enjoyed status or prosperity: The film star made an unexpected comeback. b. A return to popularity: Wide ties are
>    making a comeback this year.
> 2. **The act of making up a deficit, as in a contest or game.** https://www.thefreedictionary.com/comeback

If you want a word that only golfers will understand then I suggest Mulligan!

> Definition of mulligan : a free shot sometimes given a golfer in
> informal play when the previous shot was poorly played
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mulligan

If you want something that is over the top then how about rebirth or even resurrection.

. resurgence

. return

. revival

. recovery

The list is endless!